# Ask SQL to select data correctly

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database with all the students of a school, the year of each class and the class number. As you need to go to school for 5 years in my country, each student has 5 lines with his name in this database, but with each time different class so the line is not the same.

[image]

I want SQL to select classmates in my database. All classes are composed with different classmates but you can be two year in a row with the same classmate.

I want to know if a student has been in the same class with student 1 and student 2 but not at the same time.  If a student has been with student 1 in year 1 and with student 2 in year 3 it is ok, like this is a common student. In the picture the correct answer is Lucien Lake.

I tried this code, but it does not work because it only tells me all the students for student Paul Biloux.

```
SELECT *
FROM Lignes
WHERE (year, class) IN (SELECT year, class FROM Lignes WHERE name_student = 'Paul Biloux')
```

As I said, this code will only select all of the classmates of Paul Biloux.

I want to know if there is a common student between Paul Biloux and Jack Spiral (Lucien Lake) knowing that Paul and Jack never been in the same class together.

```
SELECT *
FROM Lignes
WHERE (year, class) IN (SELECT year, class FROM Lignes WHERE name_student = 'Paul Biloux')
AND (year, class) IN (SELECT year, class FROM Lignes WHERE name_student = 'Jack Spiral')
```

It does not work with this last code, the output is the list of students that have been in the same class of the two and not a common link. Does anyone know how to get this ?

Comment: Last query can't work because no record can meet criteria of `name_student = 'Paul Biloux' AND 'Jack Spiral'`. Perhaps: `WHERE (year, class) IN (SELECT year, class FROM Lignes WHERE name_student = 'Paul Biloux') AND (year, class) IN (SELECT year, class FROM Lignes WHERE name_student = 'Jack Spiral')`

Comment: What return do you get from your last query?

Comment: @June7 thank you for the information. it did not work, I have an error "incomplete  error" I am looking for the reason

Comment: @d0little I got nothing. No error but a blank as the output

Comment: @KenWhite Ok thank you I modified this, I am sorry. I do not know a lot about this.

Comment: I've never seen IN() used with multiple fields. Perhaps concatenate: `WHERE year & class IN (SELECT year & class ...`.

Comment: @June7 with your first formula, it selects the list of students that have been in the same class of the two. It works for two students that are in the same time in the same class if we want to know the common classmates they had.

Comment: @June7 See https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html for row values and `IN`. And `&` isn't the concatenation operator, that's `||`....

Comment: I finally had a chance to test my idea. Ooops, doesn't work at all for me. No records return. Rats. At this point, I would probably go to a VBA custom function because Access is all I have to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a CTE that returns the names of the students: `'Jack Spiral'` and `'Paul Biloux'`.
Another CTE that returns the classes/years combinations that are common between these 2 students.
Finally do a self join of the table to get all the classmates of these 2 students, group by the classmates and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
WITH
  names(name) AS (SELECT 'Jack Spiral' UNION ALL SELECT 'Paul Biloux'),
  common AS (
    SELECT class, year
    FROM Lignes
    WHERE student_name IN names
    GROUP BY class, year
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT student_name) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM names)
  )
SELECT l1.student_name student
FROM Lignes l1 INNER JOIN Lignes l2
ON l2.year = l1.year AND l2.class = l1.class AND l2.student_name <> l1.student_name
WHERE l2.student_name IN names
GROUP BY student
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT l2.student_name) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM names)
   AND SUM((l1.class, l1.year) IN common) = 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1a80c5c95c93fd31f8a83b80e835a7e4).

Comment: Thank you so much @forpas. It worked perfectly well and the demo is very useful ! It will help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

First you need to list out all classmate pairs by year, then join that result to itself for the same student in different years.  The most recent SQLLite supports common table expressions which makes this query look pretty clean:

```
With classmates AS (Select a.Class, a.Year, a.student_name as studenta, b.student_name as studentb
                From Lignes a Inner Join Lignes b ON a.Class=b.Class and a.Year=b.Year
                Where a.student_name<>b.student_name
                )
Select x.studentb, '(', x.studenta, x.Year, x.Class, ')  (', y.studentb, y.Year, y.Class, ')'
From classmates x Inner Join classmates y on x.studentb=y.studenta
Where x.Year<>y.year and x.studenta<>y.studentb
Order By x.studentb, x.studenta, y.studentb
```

This result can list the same student twice because they are connected by multiple student pairs.  If you only want to see that student name once then you can add a Group By clause to this query.

Your description was a bit incomplete, so I made an assumption that your Student1 and Student2 had to be different people in different years.  If a student repeats a class in different years, then there will be a large number of student triplets satisfying your condition for same common student.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for not being precise. When I use the code you made, I have an error "ambiguous column name : Class". Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: Do I have to replace some code by real student_name ? For example, replace a.student_name by Paul Biloux is needed ? Sorry for this question I am new at SQL.

Comment: There is a Class in both Ligne A and in Ligne B and your db manager is picky about which one to pick, even though they are both always equal.  I fixed it above.

Comment: This solution generates ALL people who fit your conditions.  1. One person in same class with two different people in different years.

Comment: This solution checks a lot of combinations and can be very slow as class sizes increase.  For example, if average class size is 25 there are 600 pairs of classmates in each class and each year which grows to 360,000 possible triplets to check.  Also, some constraint appears to be missing here.  When I went to school I was with the same core of classmates year after year.  If Lucien went to 3rd, 4th, and 5th grade with both Paul and Jack then this will identify Lucien with Paul in 3rd grade and Jack in 4th grade and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for the fixing of this technical thing, it is very kind. I am wondering if it is possible to "reverse" the code to know the "distance" in terms of common classmates between two given classmates. If the database is :           
  (1,2018,'Momo Thary'), (1,2018,'Jack Spiral'), (1,2018,'Mathilde Seine'),
 (2,2019,'Lucien Lake'), (2,2019,'Jack Spiral'), (2,2019,'Chane Way'),
 (3,2020,'Lucien Lake'), (3,2020,'Paul Biloux'), (3,2020,'Thomas Defoe'); The goal is to calculate the distance between Momo Thary (1, 2018) and Paul Biloux (3, 2020). And the answer is 2 students.

Comment: Momo T. in the same class than Jack S, then Jack S with Lucien L, and Lucien L with Paul Biloux. Two classmates between the two classmates to "link". Is SQL suited to find and explain us the "quickest" link ? Maybe it is appropriate to ask a new question according to the stackoverflow rules ?